# How to prevent other table elements not to change its position while adding new content to some TD

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

You can find the problem in the link below:

[www.yunuerenguzel.com.tr/deneme](http://www.yunuserenguzel.com.tr/deneme)

My problem is that when I click to "see Application" link, all applications of the studens are displayed under that particular row. However when the invisible row content (table) become visible, columns of the outer table slightly move to the left or right handside depending on the browser. What causes this and how can I prevent this?

Note: there is no problem in the first row if you are using Chrome.

Comment: "elements of the table replaces some amount of pixels differing from browser to browser" please explain this better. What is happening, and what do you want to happen?

Comment: I've edited the question, please look at again. Sorry for the english

Comment: What happens if you add the style, `#applicationHidden1 > table{width:100%;)` ?
It might help if you make the table inside this div always the same size.

Comment: it worked :) thank you why dont you write it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a percentage for every td.
Like :

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
    <td style="width:"50%"></td>
    <td style="width:"50%"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```